# Regex substring not in string

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that will match the following line:

```
{"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK"}, "httpCode": 200}
```

but not

```
{"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK", "config": {}}, "httpCode": 200}
```

So basically it should match the string if it not contains **config**

For checking if the string contains **status** the regex is:

```
(?=\"status\": \"OK\")
```

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: Iterate on the dictionary keys, once you find `config`, you don't match.

Comment: the regex doesn't work for me, unless I remove `?=`

Comment: It's not possible to match JSON-Data with regular expressions.

Comment: @alexm "I need to use regex". Why?

Comment: @alexm "I need to use regex" - You're opposing to finding robust solutions to your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use regex you can use the following negative look ahead based regex :

```
^((?!"config").)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD7qN2/1)

Along side the good notes by @Jerry and @nhahtdh You may note that this regex doesn't consider the type of words and i match the dictionaries that has `config` in values.(you can see the detail in [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD7qN2/1)) as a better solution you can use `json` module.

The following recursion function will do the task for any nested dictionary :

```
>>> def checker(s,val):
...    for k in s:
...        if k==val:
...           return False
...        elif isinstance(s[k],dict):
...           return checker(s[k],val)
...    return True
... 
>>> 
>>> s="""{"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK"}, "httpCode": 200}"""
>>> js=json.loads(s)
>>> checker(js,'config')
True

>>> s="""{"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK", "config": {}}, "httpCode": 200}"""
>>> js=json.loads(s)
>>> checker(js,'config')
False
```

And a nested dictionary :

```
>>> s="""{"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK", "sts":{"nested":{"config": {}}}}, "httpCode": 200}"""
>>> 
>>> js=json.loads(s)
>>> checker(js,'config')
False
```

Comment: @alexm Just as a side note, this method would be one of the slowest out there, even in the 'regex realm'. Also, the above would avoid a match if the string contains a word containing `config`, for example `nonconfig` or `sideconfigurations` and the likes.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. There is no differentiation between data and key here (apart from what Jerry has mentioned about wrong keys).

Comment: @alexm Checkout the edit!

Comment: @Jerry Yes you are right i edit the answer .thanks for reminding and attention! –

Answer (score 3):

Parse the input as JSON using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json

s = """{"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK"}, "httpCode": 200}"""
j = json.loads(s)
if "config" not in j:
    print("match")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all the other fields have to be there in that exact form, or does it suffice that it does not contain `"config"`?

```
import re
n = str({"httpStatus": "OK", "payload": {"status": "OK", "config": {}}, "httpCode": 200})
print len(re.findall("config", n)) == 0
```